# XPath: get element with position and attribute

Tags: xpath, attributes

I'm trying to get an item by its position and an attribute but do not know how.

What I want to achieve is to unite this:

```
  Xpath("//h4/a[contains(@href,'#vuln_')]")
```

and this:

```
  Xpath("//h4/a[2]")
```

How could I select the position number and attribute at a time ? I'm having trouble finding the solution.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could only guess:

```
//h4/a[contains(@href,'#vuln_') and position() = 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Xpath("//h4/a[contains(@href,'#vuln_')][2]")`